# Non-CRUD operations in repository classes

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have a Repository class for sales persons like so:

```
public class SalesPersonRepository : ISalesPersonRepository
{
     public int Add(SalesPerson salesPerson)
     {
          // Add the salesperson to the data store and return the Id
     }

     public void Update(int id, SalesPerson salesPerson)
     {
         // Update the sales person's record in the data store
     }

     public SalesPerson Get (int id)
     {
         // Fetch and return the salesperson's record
     }

    // a couple of other methods like GetAll and Delete
}
```

As you can see, I am using a SalesPerson class in which I have represented a salesperson and in my repository class, I'm using standard CRUD operations like the ones above.

However, when I run into a requirement like this: "Fetch the number of sales for the last 30, 60 and 90 days for the salesperson", "Fetch the number of customers for the salesperson" etc., I am not certain if I should return this data in the SalesPerson object.

I could add define properties like SalesPerson.ThirtyDaySaleCount, SalesPerson.SixtyDaySaleCount, SalesPerson.NinetyDaySaleCount, and assign them in the repository method, but obviously, this doesn't seem like good design.

Moreover, when I am fetching the 30, 60, 90 day sale count for the salesperson, I'm NOT interested in the other things that are defined in the SalesPerson class, like first name, last name, and other information.

So how do I return data for these specialized scenarios? Should I create specialized classes just for these, or should I just go ahead and put everything in the SalesPerson class?

PS: I know that SalesPerson is an anemic object, and I should probably think of making it non-anemic, but my immediate concern is that non-CRUD requirements are coming in thick and fast and I need to solve for that first.

Comment: Why do you need those sales? Only for reading/reporting/displaying in the UI or you need to update them as well?

Comment: Just my opinion but while ORMs work reasonably well (sometimes) for simple CRUD operations, they basically suck when it comes to more complex reporting type queries.  So yes I would use custom methods to get your sales info which in turn would just use sql queries.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Those sales are required for displaying on the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Create a specialized `ReportingRepository` returning a specialized form of SalesPerson, or use [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Comment: It is just a matter of naming convention, but I would avoid to use `Repository` for something that is not an aggregate/domain model, because then it lose the conceptual difference between a repository and a dao.

Answer (score 3):

They are just another way to see the same data of the `SalesPerson`.
I think some concepts of CQRS can be adapted to your situation.  In your case I would have something like:

```
interface SalesReportingService {
    Integer countSalesOfPeronsInPreviousDays(SalesPersonId id, Integer days)
}
```

The **value** that you need is a *number*, so the code component who need this information can use this service that will calculate it (isolating that use case from knowing how to calculate it, it express just the dependency on the query).
Then the implementation of the service can be done as the easier way with a direct implementation like `SqlSalesReportingService` (or `MongoDbSalesReportingService` or `YourPersistenceTechSalesReportingService`), or you can re-use the already created repositories.

Answer (score 1):

For these type of scenarios I also go the CQRS route and would go for an `ISalesPersonQuery` that returns either a primitive or some *read model* (DTO) that represents the data in a usable format.

Answer (score 0):

When you're messing with the database query in such a way that it "stops" being a model, you shouldn't think of it in a term of "a model".

If you do `GROUP BY`, add a `Count(*)` or in other way modify the record, you should treat it like just "a row with columns".